# Sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging in probability to $X$ and $X_n$ converging in distribution to $Z$, then $X$ has same distribution as Z?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$. Moreover suppose that $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable $Z$. My question is does $X$ have the same distribution as $Z$?

And could you please provide an proof for it?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can prove that $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution using the following facts:

1. If $X_n\to X$ in probability then $X_n\to X$ in distribution.
2. If $X_n\to X$ in distribution and $X_n\to Z$ in distribution then $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply =)